# Manhattan distance always less node expansion than misplaced tiles heuristic?

Tags: complexity-theory, search-algorithms, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I created a 8-puzzle search solver using BFS, A* with manhattan distance, and A* with misplaced tiles.

I generated data that said that for a particular random board, misplaced tiles did less node expansions to solve the board.

Is this possible?

I thought that manhattan distance is always less node expansions than misplaced tiles.

Here is the output generated from my program:

Below is 8 puzzle data search algorithm data

—----

BFS:

Number of node expansions: 876872

Board #0 l

042

368

751

Board #1 d

402

368

751

Board #2 r

302

468

751

Board #3 d

302

648

751

Board #4 r

302

658

741

Board #5 u

302

658

714

Board #6 l

302

654

718

Board #7 d

302

645

718

Board #8 l

302

615

748

Board #9 u

302

615

478

Board #10 u

302

415

678

Board #11 r

402

315

678

Board #12 d

042

315

678

012

345

678

A* with manhattan distance heuristic:

Number of node expansions: 42572

A* misplaced tiles:

Number of node expansions: 3377

Dennis